# Value of NSMutableDictionary is not changing inside the block

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I am passing the URL in this method and getting the data as output. i want to assign a new value to nsmutabledictionary but it is not assigning the value.

```
-(NSDictionary*) getDatafromURL: (NSString*)url{

    __block NSMutableDictionary *returnData=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:url parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        returnData=(NSMutableDictionary*)responseObject;
        NSLog(@"Data 1: %@",returnData);// it is printing the data

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
    NSLog(@"Data 2: %@",returnData);//  it is not printing any data

    return returnData;
}
```

in this above example the Data 1 is showing value successfully

Data 2 gives me empty dictionary.why it is not assigning the new value?

Comment: Levi's comment is correct. You can use it. But I think that you have a basic misunderstanding about object references, block variables and closures. If you want to get further information, let me know. Then I will post an answer, because it is hard to describe that in a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens because you get to the line with "Data 2" first and the block is executed only afterwards, since it is an async request. I would suggest that you change your method to something like:

```
- (void)getDataFromURL:(NSString *)url completionHandler:(void (^)(NSMutableDictionary *returnData, NSError *error))handler {
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:url parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        returnData=(NSMutableDictionary*)responseObject;
        NSLog(@"Data 1: %@",returnData);// it is printing the data
        handler(returnData, nil);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        handler(nil, error);
    }];
}
```

There might be some compile errors in the code I provided.

The other solution would be to do a synchronous request, in which case the block would be executed before the code that is after the block.

**EDIT:**

If you are choosing the first solution, you have to continue using it asynchronously. So you would call it like:

```
[self getDataFromURL:@"abc.com" completionHandler:^ (NSMutableDictionary *returnData, NSError *error) {
    // process your dictionary and the error object
}];
```

Comment: Ok how this line will be change . currently i am calling the function like this.   NSDictionary  *Info=[self getDatafromURL:@"https://www.abc.com"];

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether your Data 2 is printing before data 1? If yes, its because, the response object gets downloaded only after a certain delay. Take away the return statements. Pass the data to the dictionary to which you return the method. For eg: like

instead of 
    self.myDictionary = [self getDatafromURL:someURl];

to

```
-(void) getDatafromURL: (NSString*)url{

    __block NSMutableDictionary *returnData=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:url parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    returnData=(NSMutableDictionary*)responseObject;
    NSLog(@"Data 1: %@",returnData);// it is printing the data
    self.myDictionary = returnData;

    // Continue whatever you want to do

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

Or use the dispatch methods instead of the blocks. 
like

Or use manager waitUntilFinish method below.